# Determine Content Type of Files in Zip Archive in Java

Tags: java, archive, unzip

Environment used is Google App Engine. The zip file was uploaded in BlobStore.

I have the following code:

```
ZipInputStream zis = ...
ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
while( ze != null){
    System.out.println(ze.getName());
    ze = zis.getNextEntry();
}
```

How to determine the content type of each file in zip archive? `ze.getName` method display the name of the file. How about the file type?

Thanks

Comment: You could use the standard hackish method of extracting the extension from the filename (lastIndexOf("."))

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't the OP need additional info such as if there were no extension, or someone messed with their files and named "txt" as "pdf"? I guess just handle -1 and when the name is like "SillyFileExtension.". Just do the same stuff that you do with normal Files - regex?

Comment: @JRGalia: It is totally possible to spoof the extension, or even the file signature unless the tool is very thorough (which I doubt there is any, though). The problem is how close you want the content type detection to do: extension based, or file signature (detection of content type is at most up to the file signature from what I have seen).

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `mime type` instead of trying to guess by the file extensions, that may be missing in some cases. Here are the options to establish the `mime type` of a file:

1. Using `javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap`, like:

   ```
   System.out.println("Mime Type of " + f.getName() + " is " +
       new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f));
   ```
2. Using `java.net.URL`

   ```
   URL u = new URL(fileUrl);
   URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
   type = uc.getContentType();
   ```
3. Using `Apache Tika`

   ```
   ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
   Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
   metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, f.getName());
   Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
   // OOXMLParser parser = new OOXMLParser();
   parser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata);
   System.out.println("Mime: " + metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE));
   System.out.println("Title: " + metadata.get(Metadata.TITLE));
   System.out.println("Author: " + metadata.get(Metadata.AUTHOR));
   System.out.println("content: " + contenthandler.toString());
   ```
4. Using `JMimeMagic`

   ```
   MagicMatch match = parser.getMagicMatch(f);
   System.out.println(match.getMimeType()) ;
   ```
5. Using `mime-util`

   ```
   Collection<?> mimeTypes = MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(f);
   ```
6. Using [DROID](http://droid.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Introduction)

   ```
   Droid (Digital Record Object Identification) is a software tool to 
   perform automated batch identification of file formats.
   ```
7. [Aperture](http://aperture.wiki.sourceforge.net/Overview) framework

   ```
   Aperture is an open source library and framework for crawling and indexing
   information sources such as file systems, websites and mail boxes.
   ```

See [Get the Mime Type from a File](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) for more details for each of the above options.

In this case the easiest way is to use the first solution,  `javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap`, like:

```
MimetypesFileTypeMap mtft = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
String mimeType = mtft.getContentType(ze.getName());
System.out.println(ze.getName()+" type: "+ mimeType);
```

Comment: Im not sure which one can be used with ZipEntry.

Comment: @JRGalia See my updated answer. The easiest way is to use the first method.

Comment: it's a ZipEntry of a zip appengine file.

Comment: @Maarten Thanks, that is already the first option that I suggested in my answer :).

Comment: I don't think that this method works for `ZipEntry` (and testing suggest that I am right). supplying `ze.getName()` in `mtft.getContentType(ze.getName())` makes `MimetypesFileTypeMap` look for a file with that name on the disc, which it wants to read. Such a fiel does not exist though, because this name is just the original name of the file that is now in the zip archive. thus I get "application/octet-stream" as resut, for every file.

Comment: Does any of those also provide the compression type of the zip file? "Storage" for example?